# Social framework not found

Tags: ios, frameworks, social-networking

I reopen my project that using Social.framework, but the link binary of Social.framework was red. Before that, I was update my ios 7.0 doc set. Is Social.framework was deleted in ios 7.0 doc set ? Thanks

Comment: Right-click one of the other included frameworks, choose "show in finder". Try to search social framework in folder that opens and (if you find it) drag it back to the project. If you don't find it among other frameworks then you had probably deleted it by accident.

Comment: someday, i had a LLVM apple error that compiler needs to cleaned up my cache, then I remove all of the cache. Is that the causes of this problem?

Comment: I don't think so. Probably either the link in project files got corrupt or you really did remove Social.framework. If you can't find it among other frameworks check if it is still in the trash. Some people solved this by reinstalling XCode but i'm sure there is a faster way: try downloading from Balram as he proposed. And simply put it in the corresponding folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly select social framework from explorer & just press delete. Now click your Xcode project file & click target. In the build phase tab, kindly re add the framework by pressing + button in Link Binary With Library section.

Please note, updating doc set will not remove your framework.

If you have accidentally removed your social.framework from library itself then kindly download it from [my uploads here](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/Social.framework.zip) & extract file & put the folder Social.framework back in place.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Build setting tag?Did you mean build phases. I did't find social.framework yet, even I looking up in this directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library

Comment: If you have do not find it there in that folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer‌​/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks` then you might have probably deleted it. 
Kindly check your Trash & do a Put back.

Comment: Please download the deleted framework from my amazon bucket. Refer the link in the answer.

Comment: Done, finally i reinstall my xcode. My Social.framework turn it back again. thanks btw Balram

Comment: I'd recommend reinstalling Xcode. Downloading a system framework from an untrusted source is a bad idea™.