# Deleted a framework

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidentally deleted the social framework from my project and every time i add it again. it appears red. I think i've deleted it from my system. What can i do in order to restore the social framework, so i can use it again. Since its used in parse. What i did was clicking in the left side bar and pressed delete. instead of removing reference in build settings.

Do i need to uninstall the xcode6-beta7 or can i do something else?

[image]

Comment: You do back up your system don't you? If not, you will now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Social framework not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566721/social-framework-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have accidentally removed your social.framework from library itself then please download it from my uploads here & extract file & put the folder Social.framework back in place.

Hope that helps.

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/Social.framework.zip

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This above comment is by Balram Tiwari
It does not belong to me. To see more go to

[Social framework not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566721/social-framework-not-found)

Please don't delete your Xcode.
Waste of time.

Comment: I'd recommend reinstalling Xcode. Downloading a system framework from an untrusted source is a bad idea™.